# Fix screen flicker in Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, display, windows-registry

My notebook screen does not flickers in Linux (dual-boot alongside windows)-means my screen hardware is working. While Google-ing for this issue I found that it can be fixed by **check**ing the box under "**hide modes that this monitor cannot display**", but this option is greyed out in my PC

[image: see pic]

I have also upgraded my intel i5-4210U Graphics driver. Previously screen was working in good condition. It started flickering when I reformatted my Hard Disk to change it from MBR to GPT-type for the purpose of dual booting with Linux and then REinstalling Windows8.1. Is there any registry fix to get that greyed out box checked. 
For this laptop, when I boot into `Linux` this flicker doesn't happens.